# convert hexadecimal number string to double-precision number in java

Tags: java, numbers, hex

how can we convert hexadecimal number string to double-precision number in java ?

in matlab it's simple :

```
>> hex2num('c0399999a0000000')

ans =

  -25.6000
```

but could I do the same things in java also ?

I tried parseInt() but this number is not integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want [`Double.longBitsToDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29), like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex = "c0399999a0000000";
        long longHex = parseUnsignedHex(hex);
        double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(longHex);
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    public static long parseUnsignedHex(String text) {
        if (text.length() == 16) {
            return (parseUnsignedHex(text.substring(0, 1)) << 60)
                    | parseUnsignedHex(text.substring(1));
        }
        return Long.parseLong(text, 16);
    }
}
```

(The fact that `long` is signed in Java makes this more awkward than you'd really want, but hey...)

Comment: It's not working!  - Tried just now in my Android app.

Comment: @Daniel: "It's not working" doesn't give us any information about *exactly* what you're trying, or *exactly* what's wrong. I suggest you ask a new question showing your code in a short but complete example, linking to this question, and explaining what you're seeing vs what you expect to see.

Comment: Sorry for my immature act, here's the link to my question as you've suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55295966/10773894

Answer (score 0):

First make a long, and then call [longBitsToDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29)