# How to convert an hexadecimal string to a double?

Tags: java, android, string, hex, double

I'm getting the hexadecimal values of range 0x0000 to 0x01c2 from BLE to my phone a as `String`. In order to plot it in a graph, I have to convert it into `double`, for which I've tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10708508/10773894) but sadly it couldn't help in my case.

Here is the little modified code from the provided link:

```
String receivedData = CommonSingleton.getInstance().mMipsData; // 0x009a
long longHex = parseUnsignedHex(receivedData);
double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(longHex);

public static long parseUnsignedHex(String text) {
    if (text.length() == 16) {
        return (parseUnsignedHex(text.substring(0, 1)) << 60)
                | parseUnsignedHex(text.substring(1));
    }
    return Long.parseLong(text, 16);
}
```

Any further help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've only got values from 0x0000 to 0x01c2, it doesn't sound like that's an IEEE-754-encoded `double` value. What would you expect the result to be for 0? What would you expect the result to be for 0x01c2? What about for 0x0100?

Comment: If these are meant to be values in the range 0-450, you should just be parsing them as an `int` or `short` value. You can always then cast to `double` if you really need to.

Comment: Your code is copy-paste from there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10708508/5529263 right?

Comment: @JonSkeet 0x0000 - 0(int), 0x01c2 - 450(int) and 0x0100 - 256(int)

Comment: Right, so you shouldn't be calling `Double.longBitsToDouble`, because your hex *doesn't* represent an IEEE-754 floating point value - it's just an integer.

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please provide some coding guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value isn't a hex representation of an IEEE-754 floating point value - it's just an integer. So just parse it as an integer, after removing the leading "0x" prefix:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "0x009a";

        // Remove the leading "0x". You may want to add validation
        // that the string really does start with 0x
        String textWithoutPrefix = text.substring(2);
        short value = Short.parseShort(textWithoutPrefix, 16);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

If you really need a `double` elsewhere, you can just implicitly convert:

```
short value = ...;
double valueAsDouble = value;
```

... but I'd try to avoid doing so unless you really need to.