# Convert hexadecimal string to double in Java

Tags: java, hex, double

I want to convert this hex string *48985DDFAF27A0* to double. The result should be *49.1903648*.

I tried

1. `Double.longBitsToDouble`
2. Parsing the hex string with `parseInt(x, 16)` and then using `intBitsToFloat`

Nothing of the above approaches seems to work.

Need suggestions please

Comment: What did you try?  How did it not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an hexadecimal string to a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295966/how-to-convert-an-hexadecimal-string-to-a-double)

Comment: `Parsing the hex string with parseInt(x, 16) and then using intBitsToFloat` - this will never work for `48985DDFAF27A0` because it is equal to `20433727275345824` which is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: How do you know 48985DDFAF27A0 should be equal to 49.1903648?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash i checked it on an online converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the string of hexadecimal number to long. After doing that, you convert to double by using `Double.longBitsToDouble`. Here is an example of your hex number:

```
public class Converter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hex = "48985DDFAF27A0";
    long longHex = parseUnsignedHex(hex);
    double d =   Double.longBitsToDouble(longHex);
    System.out.println(d);
 }

public static long parseUnsignedHex(String text) {
    if (text.length() == 16) {
        return  (parseUnsignedHex(text.substring(0, 1)) << 60)
                | parseUnsignedHex(text.substring(1));
    }
    return Long.parseLong(text, 16);
}
}
```

Comment: @David remember to tick this answer then